# PERL получить из формы и сформировать

Tags: perl

Из формы получаю данные вида (name-value соответственно).

```
f40: 2930
f41: 6353
f42: 14755
f43: 21221
```

Далее пытаюсь получить значения без F

```
    foreach my $key (param()) {
    if ($key =~ /^f(\d+)$/) {
        my $gid = $1;
        if (param($key) =~ /^\d+$/) {
        my $nn{$gid} = $key;
        push(@pos, $nn);
        $hash->{nn2} = \$nn;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее нужно из БД по этим номерам сделать выборку

```
my @items = ();
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catn c WHERE c.id IN (?)");
        my $rvs = $sth->execute($hash->{nn2}) or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
        while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  
            push(@items, $item);
        }
     $hash->{items} = \@items;
```

И не работает :) Смысл в том, что нужно из формы получить номера (без f), и по ним сделать выборку.

Comment: навскидку - странный синтаксис в строке `$hash->{nn2} = /@pos;`. Там вроде слеш в другую сторону должен быть. И я бы проверил, что именно формирует первый этап (куда-нибудь в лог вывести). И будет сразу понятно, где косяк.

Comment: нигде не вижу $1 (для «Далее пытаюсь получить значения без F»)

Comment: Поправил слеш, но, конечно, проблема была не в этом. Немного не понял про $1 - где именно нужно это добавить? Я добавил, но, видимо, не верно.

Comment: вот так https://pastebin.com/PXemTrb4